# B+ Tree in H2 Database

Tags: mysql, database, h2, b-tree

I would like to implement B+ Tree in H2 database, but i want to know, **does B+ Tree facility available in H2 Database?**

Answer (score 1):

H2 already uses a B+ tree (class PageBtree).